# Initializing javascript date object with date string

Tags: javascript, datetime, simpledateformat

what date strings are considered valid to pass to the javascript date object constructor to initialize a date object.

Comment: The same strings that are deemed valid by [parse()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/parse).

Answer (score 3):

[according to MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date):

> The string should be in a format recognized by the [parse](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/parse) method (IETF-compliant RFC 2822 timestamps).